# Center menu with bootstrap 3 without breaking responsive display

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, menu, responsive-design, center

I try to center this menu, but each time I try something, it works, but it breaks the responsive display... do you know how to center it properly?

```
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="homepage-1.html">
        <img src="img/tamashi-logo-white-2.png" id="logo" class="img-responsive"/>
      </a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown active">
          <a href="#/" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Accueil<span class="caret"></  span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-flat -blue" role="menu">
            <li><a href="homepage-1.html">Marketing homepage</a></li>
            <li><a href="homepage-2.html">App homepage</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="homepage-3.html">Portfolio homepage</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="services-1.html">Le studio</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#/" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Savoir-faire<span class="caret"></  span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-flat -blue" role="menu">
            <li><a href="about-us-1.html">About us 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="about-us-2.html">About us 2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#/" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Réalisations<span class="caret"></  span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-flat -blue" role="menu">
            <li><a href="portfolio-2.html">Filterable portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="portfolio-1.html">3 column grid</a></li>
            <li><a href="portfolio-post-1.html">Portfolio post</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="contact-1.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="hidden-xs hidden-sm nav navbar-nav navbar-right" role="search">
        <li><a target="_blank" href="ui-kit.html">FR</a></li>
        <li><a target="_blank" href="components.html">EN</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- .navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- .container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: Can you please create a codepen for it?

Comment: The BS theme i'm trying to modify is this one : http://tamashi-themes.com/themes/innova/1.0.5/homepage-3.html

Answer (score 0):

You could try and wrap the nav bar in

```
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="container">
Navbar
</div>
</div>
```

Either container or container-fluid